# Make chapter number appear when referencing them

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters, ref

It seems that the \ref{} command restarts the counter for every chapter.
This makes cross-chapter references ambiguous.
Let's say I have the following:

```
Section 1
Section 2

Chapter 2
Section 1
Section 2
Section 3
```

If in Chapter 2, Section 2 I reference Chapter 1, Section 1 it will simply appear as `1` rather than `1.1`, as I'd like.

How can I make the Chapter number appear as first number when referencing?

I hope I made myself clear.
Cheers!

**Edit:** I add all the pieces of code that I think may be relevant:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{dcolumn}  
\usepackage{colordvi}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{bleudefrance}{rgb}{0.19, 0.55, 0.91}
\definecolor{royalblue}{rgb}{0.25, 0.41, 0.88}

\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{sidecap}

\usepackage{numprint}
\usepackage{makecell}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  breaklinks,
  urlcolor=royalblue,
  linkcolor=royalblue,
  citecolor=royalblue
} 

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{lineno}
\linenumbers

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.1}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\arabic{subsection}}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\arabic{subsubsection}}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\p@subsection}{}
\renewcommand{\p@subsubsection}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

{\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\newpage
\FloatBarrier
\setcounter{tocdepth}{10}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{10}
```

Comment: The behaviour you want to obtain is the standard one, so if you are not getting that then you are actively doing something to prevent this from working. Alas, without seeing your code nobody can tell.

Comment: Use `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}` instead of `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`